# What are the different terraform resource properties other than .id and .arn

Tags: terraform

How do I get more information on terraform resource properties. for example

```
aws_alb.<name>.arn
aws_alb_target_group.<name>.id
```

other than `.arn` and `.id` what other properties are available. If there is any documentation please share.

Comment: Do you have any example of what you want and is not available in TF?

Comment: sorry found it what you ment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available attributes for a resource are chosen by the provider and vary between resource types. To find out what's available you'll need to refer to the documentation of reach resource type individually.

The following are the documentation pages for the two resource types you mentioned in your question:

- [`aws_lb`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb) (the current name for what was formerly called `aws_alb`)
- [`aws_lb_target_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group) (the current name for what was formerly called `aws_alb_target_group`)

The section "Attributes Reference" on each of the resource type documentation pages describes the attributes that the resource type offers in addition to the arguments you're allowed to set directly inside the configuration.

Although many resource types in the AWS provider export `id` and `arn`, that's just a convention rather than a requirement and so you should always refer to the documentation to see what is available for a particular resource type.